# Filter multiple columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a sheet with a bunch of data. I know it is easy to filter rows so that only data in a given column shows. I can filter by surname only for example, that's easy.

Is there a way to filter with what would be in programming, an `OR`? So, say I want to find all the rows with "blue" in columns C, D, E or F.

Am I going to need a macro for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some easy work-around:

1. Go to the **empty column** G.
2. Input the following function: **=COUNTIF(C2:F2;"blue")** and copy for entire column.
3. **Rows containing values** you're looking for ("blue") will be counted.
4. Use **filter** on G column to hide all "0" ("0" means no "blue" value in C, D, E and F columns).